# Java API connect Apache Phoenix failed,ERROR 2006 (INT08)

Tags: java, hbase, apache-phoenix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOUAo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uzo0.png)

My Hadoop is 3.1.3,HBase is 2.0.5,Phoenix is 5.0.0
When i am running Java API code to connect Apache Phoenix in test,output the problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 2006 (INT08): Incompatible jars detected between client and server. Ensure that phoenix-[version]-server.jar is put on the classpath of HBase in every region server: Failed after attempts=16, exceptions:
Sun Jun 04 20:48:32 CST 2023, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1685882911171, pause=100, maxAttempts=16}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: SYSTEM:CATALOG,,1685627196784.b7ab9fb04c17719c8acf0b428e7343fd. is not online on master.hadoop.com,16020,1685882875673
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegionByEncodedName(HRegionServer.java:3272)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegion(HRegionServer.java:3249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.getRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:2390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:42010)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:304)

Sun Jun 04 20:48:32 CST 2023, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1685882911171, pause=100, maxAttempts=16}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: SYSTEM:CATALOG,,1685627196784.b7ab9fb04c17719c8acf0b428e7343fd. is not online on master.hadoop.com,16020,1685882875673
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegionByEncodedName(HRegionServer.java:3272)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegion(HRegionServer.java:3249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.getRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:2390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:42010)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:304)
```

But i have add phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0-server.jar to HBase Classpath,also i add Phoenix driver in pom.xml